# rails many association table structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, associations, data-modeling

I am trying to make an attendence tracking system in rails. I need some help designing the tables and what associations should exist in between them.

I will have schools which will then have classes and teachers assigned to every classes. There will be 50 students in every class.

So I think I should have one student table, then classes, then teachers and one attendence.

I have no idea about how should i design the attendence table and other tables as well. Can some one please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Models**

```
#app/models/school.rb
Class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :classes, class: "Class"
    has_many :teachers, through: :classes
end

#app/models/class.rb
Class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :teachers, class: "Teacher"
end

#app/models/teacher.rb
Class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :class
end

#app/models/student.rb
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :class
end
```

---

**Schemas**

```
schools
id | name | created_at | updated_at

classes
id | school_id | name | created_at | updated_at

teachers
id | class_id | name | created_at | updated_at

students
id | class_id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

---

This will allow you to call:

```
@school.classes
@school.teachers

@class.school
@class.teachers

@teacher.class

@student.class
```

Comment: thank you rich peck,what do u think about the attendence table,having 30 columns for 30days aint a proper solution.keeping it weekly or monthly might b better,u hav ny suggestion on the attendence table structure??

Comment: No, don't have 30 cols for 30 days. Have columns for the data types you wish to enter, and then submit records for each day

Comment: c i will like require attendence of every day coz if a particular studnet is absent 3days continuous,then i need some sort of alert,so that would require tracking every days attendence.what do u think??